# Get-SPUser returns additional blank lines. How do I remove them when reading into array?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to get a list of users for the site that are part of a specific domain. The end result will be putting them in a SQL DB, which is fine; I just need to get the array clean.

I am not sure which format I want to use yet.

```
Get-SPUser -web https://site.domain/site/portal -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*DOMAIN\*"} | Format-Table DisplayName, Email -HideTableHeaders

Get-SPUser -web https://site.domain/site/portal -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*DOMAIN\*"} | Format-List DisplayName, Email
```

At this point, the Format-Table and Format-List cmdlets are including extra lines.
One quick way to view that it indeed looks at them as items, is to get a count.

For instance, if I set it to a variable to get a count.

```
$a = Get-SPUser -web https://site.domain/site/portal -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*DOMAIN\*"} | Format-Table DisplayName, Email -HideTableHeaders
$a.count
```

The result will have an additional 4 lines, so I will need to account for that.

```
$a.count - 4
```

There must be a clean way to get these values, as even looping through the array still returns the blank lines.

```
Foreach ($i in $a){$i}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you getting blank lines because of your first condition `Where` ? mb you're getting blank displayname/email returned no ? otherwise, you can use a new array whenever `$i -ne ''; $newarray += $i`for example.

Comment: @Nico - Even without the Where-Object, if I return everything, the extra line padding is still there.

For instance, on a site with only 3 users, the output is like this:

BLANK LINE
UserLogin : DOMAIN\USER1
UserLogin : DOMAIN\USER2
UserLogin : DOMAIN\USER3
BLANK LINE
BLANK LINE

Comment: What if you use a new array as I wrote ?

Comment: have you tried to run the query without format-table and check the count $a.count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. You are counting the items in the `Format` result instead of the actual result.

`Format` should be used when you want to format the result. In your case the result is

```
$a = Get-SPUser -web https://site.domain/site/portal -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*DOMAIN\*"}
```

So now if you do `$a.count` you can see it gives back the correct count.

Instead of piping the result to `Format` you should pipe it to the next task for updating in the SQL database.

To explain further, if you do below command

```
    $a = Get-SPUser -web https://site.domain/site/portal -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*DOMAIN\*"} | Format-List UserLogin, DisplayName, Email
```

`$a` creates a string array and the array contains the output of the `Format` command.

Comment: That was a good thought, but does not resolve the issue. The extra lines above and below the output still exist.

Comment: @raredesign can you try to print the extra information by adding `UserLogin` also to the `Format-List` and check what value is there.

Comment: It's part of the output formatting in both Format-List and Format-Table. I just added UserLogin (| Format-List UserLogin), but the output issue was the same. I don't think it is a matter of any arguments that I output, but is the format itself. Do you have a farm to try this in so you can see what I am talking about? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @raredesign, now i understood what you are saying. Its the expected behavior. I am updating my answer

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation. I have accepted your answer. This does leave me in a position where I cannot output the format I would like to include the DisplayName and Email without the UserLogin. The output also now includes default formatting headers, even when I loop through the array. I have tested the output in both console and output text file.

Comment: Try this `Get-SPUser -web https://site.domain/site/portal -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*DOMAIN\*"} | Select-Object DisplayName,Email | export-csv "c:\output.csv"`.. and open the file in Excel.

Comment: Thanks. The Output is as follows:
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser
"DisplayName","Email"
"John Doe","jdoe@domain.com"
"Billy Bob","bbob@domain.com"

Comment: You can add `-NoTypeInformation` to the `export-csv` and that will remove `#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser`. Since its a CSV you can open it in Excel to get a tabular view.